# How to deploy spring boot microservices in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have developed few microservices and registered it into Eureka Server. Everything works fine in Local but I don't have any idea about how to deploy it into AWS Environment. Please give me some suggestion about how to deploy it into AWS.

Comment: EB is [often used](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) for spring applicaitns.

Comment: I don't now how to deploy the Spring cloud based microservices in either Elastic beanstalk or ECS.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to have it hosted on a EC2 instance if you are not worried about scalability. I would have the service turned in to a docker image, then transport that image to the EC2 instance and then use it. Though I think you can skip over the docker image process (not sure on how to do that though). Please look at this medium article for a more indept [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jamalerrakibi/deploy-your-application-with-ec2-docker-spring-boot-using-aws-cli-cb9f81260d29).